# Missing librsjni.so for armeabi cpu types

Tags: android

I'm using the following code in build.gradle

```
renderscriptTargetApi 20
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

In SDK there are  **arm64-v8a**, **armeabi-v7a**, **mips** and **x86** folders that contains librsjni.so file, So the application works fine inthe devices with this CPU architectures. But **armeabi** is missing and in Galaxy S6 with has a CPU of this type the application force closes due to not found exception for this library.

How fix this issue ?